# Don't know how to build task 'paperclip::refresh' in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am getting the error

> Don't know how to build task 'paperclip::refresh'

when I try to run `heroku run rake paperclip::refresh CLASS=Photo` in my console. This is working in my local `rake paperclip::refresh CLASS=Photo`

I already tried adding these lines to my production.rb

```
config.threadsafe!

config.dependency_loading = true if $rails_rake_task
```

I am getting an error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `threadsafe!' for #

Comment: Is that the right syntax with the two colons? I've only used rake commands with one colon. paperclip:refresh (not paperclip::refresh)

Comment: single colon is correct! `heroku run rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=Photo` worked. I never noticed that because two columns worked in my local. thanks @Tom!